# Calculate % Change from single table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have a single table of data (crimes committed) and a region that I want to compare.

I use the Percent Change function of the Crime Analysis Ribbon, I have to feed it two tables and a polygon.

Previously I have exported the table to excel, split it into two tables and re-imported it for the two dates that I want to compare (i.e Q1 vs Q2) however this seems very inefficient and wasteful and I'm sure there's a way in ArcGIS to be able to either do this without splitting the table, or split the table automatically.

The table is super simplistic its just `{Lat, Long, Date, CrimeType}`

Comment: I'm trying to skip a step in my process, right now I take the entire table, split it into two (in excel) by picking a date, then re-import it as two separate tables and use the % Change. I'd like to remove the step where I export to excel to do the data editing into two tables.

Comment: I use the `Percent Change` function of the Crime Analysis Ribbon, I have to feed it two tables and a polygon. Its ArcGIS Pro 2.3.1

Comment: Ok! Have not tried it. You could create two temporary table views using [Make Table View](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-table-view.htm), one for each date. Or [Split By Attributes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/split-by-attributes.htm)

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question. All these details should be in the body of the question. Please [Edit] the question instead of commenting.

Comment: @Vince it was in response to a question in the comment but that question was then deleted.

Comment: Yes. Please edit the Question to integrate the information in the comments which is not in the question, then remove the comments. This makes for the best possible question, without the clutter of comments.